# Can we implement testNG with play java framework?

Tags: java, testng, playframework-2.6

Can we implement testNG with play java framework? as per documentation play supports Junit(https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaTest).

If we implement testNG, will we face any issues in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps take a look at the `play-testng-plugin` developed by LinkedIn for running your TestNG tests in Play framework.

For more information please refer to the [GitHub](https://github.com/linkedin/play-testng-plugin) page.